# ubuntu 18.04 settings bug

Tags: vmware, settings

I use Ubuntu 18.04 in VMWare station pro 14, but the **Settings** don't seem to work properly.

- I cannot add a network proxy
- I cannot turn off screen lock (the button cannot turn off)
- I cannot change the background pic or lock the screen pic from the settings.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with the help of a related question here.

```
cd ~
rm -r .cache .config
```

Comment: You can also add the link for that question in references. :-)